# How to add facebook as Web Service on Netbeans

Tags: java, facebook, web-services, netbeans

I'm following this netbeans tutorial to create a facebook app on Netbeans 7.1. http://documents.cofares.net/netbeans.org/kb/docs/websvc/facebook.html

In Step 12
When i am asked to select the REST resources "From IDE registered" gives me the sample ones such as Twitter, Amazon, Google . but NOT the "facebook",

So I tried to add facebook as a web service in Services window. 
When I'm adding web service Netbeans asks me a local file Or URL.

I tried to give this URL for adding facebook as web service https://graph.facebook.com
but it says:
"*can't determine whether service is WSDL or WADL*"
What is the correct URL that I can use here?

Answer (score 2):

http://documents.cofares.net/netbeans.org/kb/docs/websvc/facebook.html

NetBeans IDE Facebook support does not currently include support for OAuth, Extended Permissions, or the Graph API. Work on this is in progress.